# How to download Git's code using SourceTree

Tags: git, authentication, atlassian-sourcetree

I have created a project in git.oschina.net (via website).

I wish to checkout this project using Atlassian SourceTree, but have failed to do so. Please note that I am using a foreign language with my client.

I have received the following error message : Authentication failed for 'https://gitee.com/weidu23/EduInfoProj.git/'

You can see the error message snapshots below :

[SourceTree repository URL dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MjIU.jpg)

[SourceTree Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6LKu.jpg)

Can anyone please help with this issue? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the credentials you use to authenticate with that server? Does SourceTree have its own list of credentials it uses?

Comment: You obviously need to provide credentials in order to connect to your GIT repository and download your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try go to:

```
~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree
```

and then look for a file similar to **username\@STAuth-path.to.gitrepository.com** and delete it.

You will be prompted for a new password

Answer (score 0):

Goto SourceTree Preferences > Accounts

Add your account.

Comment: Meaning credentials - user/password.

Comment: Yes. Add your credentials.